# Are feed group and feed id available as separate variables in aggregation formats

Tags: getstream-io

The [documentation](https://getstream.io/docs/#aggregated-feeds) says the following variables are available:

> `feed_group`: the feed group (e.g. timeline)
>   `feed_id`: the feed id (e.g. 123)

However, when I preview this aggregation format `{{ feed_group }}_!_{{ feed_id }}` the result is something like `_!_timeline_aggregated:040fd3ae-ad3b-4e64-95f9-32da6daff105`, indicating `feed_id` contains the full feed string and `feed_group` is blank or undefined.

Is there any way to get separate feed_group and feed_id strings as the docs indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edited after conversation in the comments]

There was an unfortunate consistency in the docs which has been updated since. `feed_group` was indeed not set and the `feed_id` contained the `feed_group` as well, divided from the id with a semicolon (:).

For backward compatibility only the docs have been updated. The `feed_id` is now something like `notification:123` and the `feed_group` is no longer a documented variable. Also `verb.id` got renamed to just `verb`.

Comment: No, the `feed_group` variable contains no value, and `feed_id` appears to contain `{{ feed_group }}:{{ feed_id }}`, instead of what's indicated in the docs.

To be more clear, if I had an individual feed called `timeline_aggregated:12345`, the docs indicate that `feed_group` should equal "timeline_aggregated" and `feed_id` should equal "12345". In reality, `feed_id` equals "timeline_aggregated:12345" and `feed_group` equals "".

Comment: @dkeen I meant: there's probably no need for a feed_group variable, because it is inherent to the feed group where you are configuring the aggregate config for. Or you can do a string operation with a substr till the first colon, then trim the rest of the string.

Comment: Specifically, I'm trying to change the aggregate group depending on if the `feed_id` (just the part after the colon) == the id of the activity `object`. As far as I can tell, there's no way to do that kind of substring operation in the jinja2 template. Any time I try to use a jinja2 filter on the dashboard, the preview returns "the format contains syntax errors".